# VS code python attribute suggestion

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with Intellisense. Even though Python, Pylance and even Visual Studio IntelliCode extensions are installed, VS code is still unable to suggest object attributes.

Could you please advise any settings.json parameters which will trigger python attribute suggestion globally ?

Sometime it's tedious to remember all object attributes without documentation being opened.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctrl + space for windows  for activating intelliSense in VsCode.

However it also depends on processing speed of computer.

Comment: I am aware of this but the only thing it does is "No Suggestions"

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense was provided by the Language Server. The search paths depend on the python interpreter you have selected.

If you modify the `PYTHONPATH` manually to import the package, you need to add these locations to the Language Server too(settings.json), like this:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/lib/flask-0.12"]
```

You can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_enable-intellisense-for-custom-package-locations).

Or, there are some problems of your Language Server, you can have a look at the
`OUTPUT` panel --> `Python Language Server` channel. And attach the error message on the question.

Comment: My settings.json contain "python.defaultInterpreterPath" but that venv contains all the libraries needed to execute the script. Do I have to add extrapaths anyway? 

Ezsheets python library is installed in the venv used, but attributes are not suggested anyway.

Comment: All the Intellisense not work, or just some modules? And which python interpreter have you selected?

Comment: I think Intellisense does work most of the time only to a certain level. Intellisense doesn't suggest rowCount attribute for ezsheets sheet object as visible on above image. Intellisense also doesn't suggest tag_name attribute for selenium webelement objects

Answer (score 0):

Long time Vim&ctrl-p user, new to vscode.

[image: strl+space shows no suggestions on python attribute access]

This is a fresh install with only the Microsoft IntelliSense (Pylance) language server & vscodevim.  I verified simple "word based suggestions" is enabled in settings:

```
{
"editor.wordBasedSuggestionsMode": "allDocuments",
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true
}
```

When I hover over "component" the type is "Any" - but I'd still like to be able to guess autocomplete based on surrounding words.

I was able to get the "desired" word based auto-complete behavior (suggestions prefixed with "abc") by disabling the Microsoft Python IntelliSense (Pylance) exstention.  I'm going to look for [alternatives](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21611).